# highcharts move a point using pixels

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart as an example. I would like to move the points over B such that 1% is over the orange column, and the 2% is over the blue column. Is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/0m3208qj/4/

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

The points are positioned according to the y value. So if you need increae position of it, you need to prepare another y values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this, but in a complicated way. I had to split the points into two series, use pointPlacement to move them to the correct place, and then use the renderer to draw custom lines!

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8datkr4m/

`Code`